# Unable to locate Ubuntu packages during docker build

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

... with various errors such as

```
Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]`
```

It's failing well before reaching the point it needs to copy local files, so you can run it and hopefully reproduce.

Dockerfile: https://pastebin.com/BAsJ2BzF

As suggested elsewhere I first attempted to `docker system prune`.
Also, out of 500gb I still have more than 126gb free. Can this really be a local file system space issue?

Comment: Are you using Docker in a Mac? if it is, you probably need to add more storage in the settings

Comment: Huh. Didn't know that... it helped! Please feel free to write as answer.

Comment: Have you tried to split operation from line 35 to line 84 in multiple steps and debug them?
You're doing quite a lot of tasks in the same operation, you're doing it to save space on layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the disk size in the docker settings.

[image: Docker for Mac preferences][image: Docker for Mac change disk size]